# Random Characters PHP Decode Nested JSON

Tags: php, json, api

Really struggling with this one. I have connected to the API fine and can get the raw JSON Data.

But when I am trying to decode it I just get a load of random characters.
The JSON path should be response->data->fieldData->Case_ID
There are other fields there also but I have hidden them to make it easier to read.

This is my JSON

```
{
    "response": {
        "dataInfo": {
            "database": "MicroLog",
            "layout": "External_API_Cases",
            "table": "Cases",
            "totalRecordCount": 143691,
            "foundCount": 23,
            "returnedCount": 2
        },
        "data": [
            {
                "fieldData": {
                    "Case_ID": 139220,
                },
                "portalData": {},
                "recordId": "139261",
                "modId": "138"
            },
            {
                "fieldData": {
                    "Case_ID": 143421,
                },
                "portalData": {},
                "recordId": "143462",
                "modId": "25"
            }
      ]
    },
    "messages": [
        {
            "code": "0",
            "message": "OK"
        }
    ]
}
```

The code I have been using.

```
<?php
include('login.php');

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'URL_HERE',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "query": [
        {
            "Closed": "1",
            "Closed_TimeStamp": "06/24/2021"
        }
    ],
    "limit": 2
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$token.'',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$decode = json_decode($response,true);


foreach ($decode['response']['data'] as $dec) {
    foreach ($dec['fieldData'] as $cd) {
    echo $cd['Case_ID'];
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

This is what it returns

> 188B7162M111662J>41ISS1AM1200000000000J5D
> 118A7162I11162J�62ISS1AM120000000000J5D

Comment: Not sure what is happening, but I couldn't get your sample to run (it may be due to removing the extra data).  But using `echo $dec['fieldData']['Case_ID'];` in the outer loop gave me the value I would expect.

Comment: @NigelRen I could've sworn I had tried that combination. I think I have tried to many now its all muddled!
But what you have said seems to work perfectly!